# Simple inverse Kinematic algorithm

Tags: kinematics, inverse-kinematics, c++

I was looking for a simple inverse Kinematic algorithm that doesn't depend on eigen(doesn't work on my machine + dependency conflict never fixed it)

Most of the code out in the internet is way to complex and has eigen3 as a Dependency.

If the code is in C or C++ it would be highly appreached!

Does anyone know of a code that fits those requirements?

My OS is debian lastest stable version (don't know the exact version).

Last time I was looking at code it required Eigen3 and setting it up was always complaining about problems.

Comment: Is there a special reason why eigen does not run? Should work OK on Debian.

Comment: `was always complaining about problems.` well okay, but what was it telling you? It's going to be really, really difficult for you to find code, for free, in C++, that does inverse kinematics, where that software also uses a homemade method for solving systems of equations. It would be a much, **much** better use of your time to find out what eigen needs than to find a kinematics library that doesn't use it.

Comment: How general purpose do you need the IK library to be?  (How complex is your arm?).  Because if you have just a few joints, you can find simple solutions in textbooks and probably just write your own.  But full-fledged IK for a 7 DOF arm is pretty complex...